# Error in Manifest.xml file in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest

I tried to change the start activity from the manifest file but it keeps erroring and the app crashing on the emulator.
Here is my Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.project1">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/CardView.Light">

    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity">

    </activity>
    **<activity** android:name=".SignInActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AccountSettingsActivity">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

The word "activity" surrounded with stars is erroring. When I remove the "intent-filter" it's okay but when I put it the error begins. If someone has any idea on how to fix that, I'd be glad to know.

Comment: If by "erroring" you mean that the IDE editor window is showing an error, if you are using Android Studio and have a mouse, you can hover your mouse over the error indicator to get a popup explaining what the problem is. Or, if you build the project, the build process will tell you what the problem is. Most likely, you need to add `android:exported="true"` to the `<activity>` element.

Comment: HI, I tried this, with exported=true, but it still doesn't compile

Comment: Then you will need to read the error message that the tools are giving you, and then take action to fix whatever the tools are complaining about.